# spring ldap dependencies in pom.xml - exception

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I use spring LDAP.

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
        group-search-filter="member={0}"/>

</authentication-manager>

<sec:ldap-server url="ldap://__server__.com:389" />
```

pom.xml:
        
            org.springframework.ldap
            spring-ldap
            1.3.0.RELEASE
            pom
            provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception when run (`mvn tomcat:run`):

> ```
> sparklr2 19:04:24.925 [ERROR] DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
> <org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Couldn't locate: org.s
> pringframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource.  If you are using LD
> AP with Spring Security, please ensure that you include the spring-ldap jar file
>  in your application; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.
> springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource>org.springframework.
> context.ApplicationContextException: Couldn't locate: org.springframework.ldap.c
> ore.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource.  If you are using LDAP with Spring Securi
> ty, please ensure that you include the spring-ldap jar file in your application;
>  nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ldap.
> core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource
> ```

I can see in the `.m2` folder

```
m2\repository\org\springframework\ldap\spring-ldap-core\1.3.0.RELEASE\spring-ldap-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
```

which has

```
spring-ldap-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar\org\springframework\ldap\core\support\BaseLdapPathContextSource.class
```

What is missing? How to resolve the exception?

Comment: What is `spring-ldap-core-tiger`? Anyway, i have used spring ldap via maven a number of times and i just needed to set `spring-security-ldap` in pom.xml

Comment: I am following http://www.springsource.org/ldap. Anyway, the issue was not in pom. Something to do with dependencies between tonr and sparklr projects (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth) where I updated 2nd project to use spring LDAP and I am trying to run tonr and dependent ldap jars were not getting copied to WEB-INF. That is resolved, but stuck with something else now :(